# Multiple query event failing

Tags: mysql, sql, events, transactions

what happens if an event on mysql database has 4 queries and it crashes on query #3? Are there any implicit transaction to do the rollback?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on Your server settings :

```
SET autocommit=0;
```

Comment: so event must be like this?

SET autocommit = 0;
query;
query;
SET autocommit = 1;

Comment: Your event should start with `START TRANSACTION;` and end with `COMMIT;`. I'm not sure if you can `SET autocommit=0` in an event, but if you do you will have to `COMMIT` anyway when you set it back to 1.

Comment: Ok, that's what I missed.

Thank you.

Comment: One more question: if que transaction fails and event was "ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE", will it remain on database?